# dojo Filtering Select not working Properly

Tags: dojo, filtering

I am trying to use following code for implemeting dojo Filtering Select but getting weird display with no errors.

I have just replaced source js file due to which functionality is working but issue is still there

http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.2.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Simple FilterSelect Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  @import "../dijit/themes/soria/soria.css";
  @import "/resources/dojo.css";
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.2.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.require("dojo.parser");
 dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
 </script>
</head>
<body class="soria">
  <select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="countryName" autocomplete="true"
  value="sel">
  <option value="sel" selected="selected">Austria</option>
  <option value="1" >Australia</option>
  <option value="2" >Canada</option>
  <option value="3" >Germany</option>
  <option value="4" >Japan</option>
  <option value="5" >United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="6" >United States of America</option>
  <option value="7" >Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="8" >Albania</option>
  <option value="9" >Algeria</option>
  <option value="10" >American Samoa</option>
  <option value="11" >Andorra</option>
  <option value="12" >Angola</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work, however I suspect your stylesheets aren't loading. Try this from Google's CDN:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Simple FilterSelect Example</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2.3/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css";
  @import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.2.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 dojo.require("dojo.parser");
 dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");
 </script>
</head>
<body class="soria">

<div style="padding:2em"><!-- for visibility -->

  <select dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="countryName" autocomplete="false"
  value="sel" queryExpr="*${0}*">
  <option value="sel" selected="selected">Austria</option>
  <option value="1" >Australia</option>
  <option value="2" >Canada</option>
  <option value="3" >Germany</option>
  <option value="4" >Japan</option>
  <option value="5" >United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="6" >United States of America</option>
  <option value="7" >Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="8" >Albania</option>
  <option value="9" >Algeria</option>
  <option value="10" >American Samoa</option>
  <option value="11" >Andorra</option>
  <option value="12" >Angola</option>
  </select>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I'd recommend to tweak the filteringselect to have `autocomplete="false"` and `queryExpr="*${0}*"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it might be the CSS/styles issue  - 
please check the Net tab in firebug to ensure there are no 404s

also I just created a jsfiddle with your markup and it seems to work pretty well in popular browsers. checkout:

http://jsfiddle.net/jA4KX/

you can change the fiddle to match your dojo version and play with it

hth